# Third fragment wont get replaced, just added on top

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-framelayout

I've got 3 simple fragments (for testing purposes)

Fragment1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/frameLHaupt"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".pkgActivity.FragmentHaupt">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
    
</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Fragment2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frameLActionBar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".pkgActivity.FragmentActionBar">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="149dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="174dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nextFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="next fragment" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/lastFragment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="last fragment" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Bro welcome custom actionbar" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and Fragment3:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frameLayoutViewPager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".pkgActivity.FragmentViewPager">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Calling Fragment1 -> Fragment2:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLHaupt, fragment2);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

=> This code works just fine, the fragment1 framelayout gets replaced by the framelayout of the fragment

But when I call Fragment2 -> Fragment3:

```
FragmentViewPager fragment2 = new FragmentViewPager();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLActionBar, fragment2);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

=> The Fragment3 wont get replaced but rather added on top of fragment2. W

I tried ussing `getActivity().getSuportFragmentManager()` but the result remains the same, the fragment3 gets added on top of fragment2.
What can be the cause be? Am I missing something?

Comment: Just checking: is `R.id.frameLActionBar` a unique id within your view tree? As in, it's not replacing some other layout that just happens to be on top?

Comment: Also try `parentFragmentManager` or something...

Comment: You seem to be using two different containers, `R.id.frameLHaupt` and `R.id.frameLActionBar`?

Comment: @EdwardVanRaak yes, frameLActionbar is unique and is only used im my fragment 2

Comment: @HenryTwist yes, cause i have an own container for each fragment

Comment: So by using different containers, `replace` isn't replacing anything, hence the fragments not getting replaced? Or have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: @HenryTwist the problem is that only the fragment1 gets replaced with fragment2 but fragment2 doesn't get replaced by fragment3. fragment3 just gets added to fragment2, which shouldn't be. fragment3 should replace fragment2, but it doesn't. it just gets added to fragment2. thus, I'm trying to find out why the fragment2 doesn't get replaced by fragment3.

Comment: There are no code references to `fragment3` so I am not sure what your issue could be.

Comment: @HenryTwist the code reference is the last code snippet. I called the variable 'fragment2' but that is the third fragment. i just called is fragment2 since its the second fragment that gets called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're using different containers for all of your fragments. When you replace a fragment, the container ID represents the container the fragment lives in, **not** the ID of the view you're looking to replace. So using the new fragment root as the fragment container is placing each fragment inside the previous one.

Comment: So I should always use: fragmentTransaction.replace(MAINCONTAINERID, fragment);?

Comment: Yes, if you want to actually replace it. Otherwise you're not replacing anything, you're adding a fragment to a previously empty container.

Comment: thanks, ill try it when I get home and let you know if it works, so I can mark your answer as accepted. But then how come i managed to replace the activtiy framelayout with fragment1. and then replacing fragment1 with fragment2 also worked.

Comment: Good question, maybe you're also using different fragment managers? That would also cause fragments to not be replaced.

Comment: yeah could be, I'll check when I get home. As far as I can remember I always used getFragmentManager(); I'll let u know :)

Comment: it worked, the issue was that I wasnt using the same containerid. thanks for the help. I accepted ur answer and upvoted it.